# Linux Directory Access Permission

Tags: linux, permissions, command

Two directories have the same permissions like this

drwxrw-rw- 2 user_1 users  4096 May 10 23:03 lg-x1

drwxrw-rw- 2 user_1 users  4096 May 11 17:22 lg-c2

when access lg-x1 with user_1, it shows: '-hash cd: lg-x1: Permission denied' ;
but lg-c2 is accessable. 
Both lg-x1 and lg-c2 are accessable when login with root.

what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a directory in Linux you need execute permissions. Only root has it, therefore other users cannot access it. Add x with the relevant `sudo chmod` you need

Comment: But lg-c2 is accessable. And user_1 belongs to group 'users'

Comment: Regardless you need x privileges to access a directory. If you still can, perhaps there is something else in your settings, maybe that user has some root privileges.